# How do I make a variable from outside a function work in that function?

Tags: php

```
function nothing() { 
    echo $variableThatIWant; 
}
```

Comment: Please don't use global variables. See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put "global" before the variable you want to use, Like this :

```
<?php
    $txt = "Hello";
    function Test() {
        global $txt;
        echo $txt;
    }
    Test();
?>
```

OR :
you can passed it as parameter, Like this :

```
<?php
    $txt = "Hello";
    function Test($txt) {
        echo $txt;
    }
    Test($txt);
?>
```

source : http://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/php-global-variables

Answer (score 4):

The better way is to pass it as an argument.

```
function nothing($var) {
    echo $var;
}

$foo = 'foo';
nothing($foo);
```

The evil way, and I dont know why I'm even showing you this, is to use global.

```
function nothing() {
    global $foo;
    echo $foo;
}

$foo = 'foo';
nothing();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `global`.

```
$var = 'hello';

function myprint()
{
   global $var;
   echo $var;
}
```

Comment: While this works.. OP: Keep in mind globals are almost always the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a [class property](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) (or member variable) if you are inside a class:

```
<?php

$myClass = new MyClass();
echo $myClass->nothing();

class MyClass {

  var $variableThatIWant = "something that I want";

  function nothing() { 
    echo $this->variableThatIWant; 
  }
}
```

[Codepad example](http://codepad.org/7B1Ikqw2)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) if you want to modify it inside the function without having to return it:

```
$a = "hello";
myFunction($a);
$a .= " !!";
echo $a; // will print : hello world !!

function myFunction(&$a) {
  $a .= " world";
}
```

[Codepad example](http://codepad.org/FoKX56Vy)